# Svelte property not updating as expected in Sveltestrap Modal component

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component, sveltestrap

I am a React user, and am having trouble understanding how and when values get updated in svelte. I'm just trying to pass a value into a component updated via a user action. Here are the basics of my code:

```
<script>
import {Modal, ModalBody} from 'sveltestrap';

let currentPollType = null;

const myPoll = {
    type: 1,
    // ...
};

const onClickBroadcast = function(e, poll) {
    console.log(poll.type);
    currentPollType = poll.type;
    console.log('currentPollType', currentPollType);  // set correctly here
};
</script>

<button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
    on:click={(e) => onClickBroadcast(e, myPoll)}>
    Broadcast
</button>

<Modal isOpen={true} size="lg">
    <ModalBody>
        Poll type: {currentPollType}  (always null)
    </ModalBody>
</Modal>
```

So, what am I doing wrong here? The `currentPollType` prop is always `null` in the child component.

Comment: [Your code seems to be working nicely](https://svelte.dev/repl/9d775523d80546b4aea990ecab4fdc33?version=3.55.0).

Comment: Thanks for testing this out. It looks like the issue in my application may be due to rendering PollResponses inside a [sveltestrap Modal](https://sveltestrap.js.org/?path=/story/components--modals)

Comment: Yes, my code works fine outside the sveltestrap Modal. So, this appears to be an issue with nesting components. I've updated my example code for illustration. Here is the Modal code, with content defined in a `<slot>`. I don't see the problem, from looking at the code: https://github.com/bestguy/sveltestrap/blob/master/src/ModalBody.svelte

Comment: Interesting. It's not impossible that it is a subtle `slot` bug in Svelte at play. It will be hard to say without a minimal, reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct, and there seems to be no issues arising when running your example [directly](https://svelte.dev/repl/672a5dae41b047b482c6979c8d265065?version=3.55.0).

But if you meant that it is showing `null` on startup then changing the `modalBody` slot to

```js
{currentPollType ? currentPollType : 0}
```

should do the trick.